# OrderBy MDX Queries?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

This is my MDX Query.

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
{(
    [Products].[Item Description].children,
    [Calendar].[Date].[Date]
)}
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns
FROM [SalesReport])
```

This gives the sales records in quantity and net sales as expected. We need now to sort it to get the item which has the highest quantity in first. In other words, we're looking to apply 'descending' sort here.

I tried all order method which gives me error. Can you please help me to get my wish done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the below ?

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
ORDER((
    [Products].[Item Description].children,
    [Calendar].[Date].[Date]
), [Measures].[Quantity], DESC)
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns
FROM [SalesReport])
```

**Second attempt [WORKING SOLUTION]**

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
ORDER((
    [Products].[Item Description].children    
), [Measures].[Quantity], DESC)
*[Calendar].[Date].[Date]
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns
FROM [SalesReport])
```

Comment: NON EMPTY
ORDER(
    [Products].[Item Description].children,
    [Measures].[Quantity], DESC)
on rows

This works great but below query this doesn't work

NON EMPTY
ORDER((
    [Products].[Item Description].children,
    [Calendar].[Date].[Date]
), [Measures].[Quantity], DESC)
on rows

Comment: Try my second attempt.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti (upped) I like this solution. Although slightly surprised `BDESC` wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to further order the inner group you could do this:

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
ON 0,
NON EMPTY

  GENERATE(
  ORDER(
  [Products].[Item Description].children 
  ,[Measures].[Quantity], BDESC)
  ,
  ORDER(
  [Products].[Item Description].CURRENTMEMBER  //<< possibly [Products].CURRENTMEMBER
  *
  {[Calendar].[Date].[Date].Members}
  ,[Measures].[Quantity], BDESC))

ON 1
FROM
(
  SELECT
  {
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
  }
  ON 0
  FROM [SalesReport]
);
```